# Can't delete entity with hibernate

Tags: java, entity-framework, hibernate, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

i'm not able to delete an entity from my database with Spring-data Jpa (hibernate). When i call the method delete of hibernate from JpaRepository, there is no mistake or exception but my FactureSortie entity isn't deleted.
Here is my models:

> Facture, superclass of FactureSortie :

```
package be.afelio.GEDFacture.entities;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.persistence.Basic;
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

/**
 *
 * @author johan
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "facture")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Facture.findAll", query = "SELECT f FROM Facture f")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Facture.findByIdFacture", query = "SELECT f FROM Facture f WHERE f.idFacture = :idFacture")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Facture.findByMontantHTVA", query = "SELECT f FROM Facture f WHERE f.montantHTVA = :montantHTVA")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Facture.findByMontantTVAC", query = "SELECT f FROM Facture f WHERE f.montantTVAC = :montantTVAC")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Facture.findByMontantTVA", query = "SELECT f FROM Facture f WHERE f.montantTVA = :montantTVA")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Facture.findByDateFacturation", query = "SELECT f FROM Facture f WHERE f.dateFacturation = :dateFacturation")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Facture.findByNumerocomptable", query = "SELECT f FROM Facture f WHERE f.numerocomptable = :numerocomptable")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Facture.findByUuid", query = "SELECT f FROM Facture f WHERE f.uuid = :uuid")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Facture.findByNumeroPiece", query = "SELECT f FROM Facture f WHERE f.numeroPiece = :numeroPiece")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Facture.findByValidee", query = "SELECT f FROM Facture f WHERE f.validee = :validee")})
public class Facture implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "id_Facture")
    private Integer idFacture;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "Montant_HTVA")
    private double montantHTVA;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "Montant _TVAC")
    private double montantTVAC;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "Montant_TVA")
    private double montantTVA;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "Date_Facturation")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date dateFacturation;
    @Column(name = "Numero_comptable")
    private Integer numerocomptable;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "uuid")
    private String uuid;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "numero_piece")
    private int numeroPiece;
    @Column(name = "validee")
    private Boolean validee;
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "facture")
    private FactureSortie factureSortie;
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "facture")
    private FactureEntree factureEntree;
    @JoinColumn(name = "imputation", referencedColumnName = "Imputation")
    @ManyToOne
    private Projet imputation;

    public Facture() {
    }

    public Facture(Integer idFacture) {
        this.idFacture = idFacture;
    }

    public Facture(Integer idFacture, double montantHTVA, double montantTVAC, double montantTVA, Date dateFacturation, String uuid, int numeroPiece) {
        this.idFacture = idFacture;
        this.montantHTVA = montantHTVA;
        this.montantTVAC = montantTVAC;
        this.montantTVA = montantTVA;
        this.dateFacturation = dateFacturation;

        this.uuid = uuid;
        this.numeroPiece = numeroPiece;
    }

    public Integer getIdFacture() {
        return idFacture;
    }

    public void setIdFacture(Integer idFacture) {
        this.idFacture = idFacture;
    }

    public double getMontantHTVA() {
        return montantHTVA;
    }

    public void setMontantHTVA(double montantHTVA) {
        this.montantHTVA = montantHTVA;
    }

    public double getMontantTVAC() {
        return montantTVAC;
    }

    public void setMontantTVAC(double montantTVAC) {
        this.montantTVAC = montantTVAC;
    }

    public double getMontantTVA() {
        return montantTVA;
    }

    public void setMontantTVA(double montantTVA) {
        this.montantTVA = montantTVA;
    }

    public Date getDateFacturation() {
        return dateFacturation;
    }

    public void setDateFacturation(Date dateFacturation) {
        this.dateFacturation = dateFacturation;
    }


    public Integer getNumerocomptable() {
        return numerocomptable;
    }

    public void setNumerocomptable(Integer numerocomptable) {
        this.numerocomptable = numerocomptable;
    }

    public String getUuid() {
        return uuid;
    }

    public void setUuid(String uuid) {
        this.uuid = uuid;
    }

    public int getNumeroPiece() {
        return numeroPiece;
    }

    public void setNumeroPiece(int numeroPiece) {
        this.numeroPiece = numeroPiece;
    }

    public Boolean getValidee() {
        return validee;
    }

    public void setValidee(Boolean validee) {
        this.validee = validee;
    }

    public FactureSortie getFactureSortie() {
        return factureSortie;
    }

    public void setFactureSortie(FactureSortie factureSortie) {
        this.factureSortie = factureSortie;
    }

    public FactureEntree getFactureEntree() {
        return factureEntree;
    }

    public void setFactureEntree(FactureEntree factureEntree) {
        this.factureEntree = factureEntree;
    }

    public Projet getImputation() {
        return imputation;
    }

    public void setImputation(Projet imputation) {
        this.imputation = imputation;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (idFacture != null ? idFacture.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof Facture)) {
            return false;
        }
        Facture other = (Facture) object;
        if ((this.idFacture == null && other.idFacture != null) || (this.idFacture != null && !this.idFacture.equals(other.idFacture))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Models.Facture[ idFacture=" + idFacture + " ]";
    }

}
```

> FactureSortie :

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package be.afelio.GEDFacture.entities;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Basic;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.PrimaryKeyJoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

import org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Parameter;

/**
 *
 * @author johan
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "facture_sortie")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "FactureSortie.findAll", query = "SELECT f FROM FactureSortie f")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "FactureSortie.findByIdFacture", query = "SELECT f FROM FactureSortie f WHERE f.idFacture = :idFacture")})
public class FactureSortie implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
//  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
//  @Basic(optional = false)
  @GeneratedValue(generator="sharedKeyFactureSort")
  @GenericGenerator(name="sharedKeyFactureSort", strategy = "foreign", parameters = @Parameter(name="property", value="facture"))
  @Column(name = "id_facture")
    private Integer idFacture;
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_client", referencedColumnName = "id_client")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Client idClient;
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_commande", referencedColumnName = "id_commande")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Commande idCommande;
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_facture", referencedColumnName = "id_Facture", insertable = false, updatable = true)
    @OneToOne(optional = false)
    private Facture facture;
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_prestation", referencedColumnName = "id_prestation")
    @ManyToOne
    private Prestation idPrestation;
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_type_vente", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private TypeVente idTypeVente;

    public FactureSortie() {
    }

    public FactureSortie(Integer idFacture) {
        this.idFacture = idFacture;
    }

    public Integer getIdFacture() {
        return idFacture;
    }

    public void setIdFacture(Integer idFacture) {
        this.idFacture = idFacture;
    }

    public Client getIdClient() {
        return idClient;
    }

    public void setIdClient(Client idClient) {
        this.idClient = idClient;
    }

    public Commande getIdCommande() {
        return idCommande;
    }

    public void setIdCommande(Commande idCommande) {
        this.idCommande = idCommande;
    }

    public Facture getFacture() {
        return facture;
    }

    public void setFacture(Facture facture) {
        this.facture = facture;
    }

    public Prestation getIdPrestation() {
        return idPrestation;
    }

    public void setIdPrestation(Prestation idPrestation) {
        this.idPrestation = idPrestation;
    }

    public TypeVente getIdTypeVente() {
        return idTypeVente;
    }

    public void setIdTypeVente(TypeVente idTypeVente) {
        this.idTypeVente = idTypeVente;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (idFacture != null ? idFacture.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof FactureSortie)) {
            return false;
        }
        FactureSortie other = (FactureSortie) object;
        if ((this.idFacture == null && other.idFacture != null) || (this.idFacture != null && !(this.idFacture == other.idFacture))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Models.FactureSortie[ idFacture=" + idFacture + " ]";
    }

}
```

> Here is my FactureSortieService that call FactureSortieDAO:

```
 package be.afelio.GEDFacture.business.impl;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import org.dozer.DozerBeanMapper;
import org.dozer.Mapper;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.data.domain.PageRequest;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import be.afelio.GEDFacture.business.ClientService;
import be.afelio.GEDFacture.business.CommandeService;
import be.afelio.GEDFacture.business.FactureService;
import be.afelio.GEDFacture.business.FactureSortieService;
import be.afelio.GEDFacture.business.ProjectService;
import be.afelio.GEDFacture.dao.FactureSortieDAO;
import be.afelio.GEDFacture.dto.ClientDto;
import be.afelio.GEDFacture.dto.FactureSortieDto;
import be.afelio.GEDFacture.dto.ProjetDto;
import be.afelio.GEDFacture.entities.Client;
import be.afelio.GEDFacture.entities.FactureSortie;
import be.afelio.GEDFacture.entities.Projet;
import be.afelio.GEDFacture.tools.DtoConverter;

@Component
public class FactureSortieServiceImpl implements FactureSortieService {
    @Autowired
    private FactureSortieDAO factureSortieDAO;
    @Autowired
    private ProjectService projetService;

    @Autowired
    private FactureService factureService;
    @Autowired
    private CommandeService commandeService;
    @Autowired
    private ClientService clientService;
    private Mapper mapper = new DozerBeanMapper();

    /**
     * @param facture
     *
     *            call the add method of different services to add data in
     *            database. call createProjet to add a project in database and
     *            get the new projectid call add of factureService to add a
     *            facture in database and get the new factureid call addCommande
     *            of the commandeService to add a commande and get the new
     *            commandeid Set the id of the facture to null because hibernate
     *            doesn't handle the non-null id to add save the facture and get
     *            it.
     */

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public FactureSortieDto addFacture(FactureSortieDto facture) {

        try {
            FactureSortie sortie = DtoConverter.convertFactureDto(facture);
            sortie.getFacture().setImputation(projetService.createProjet(sortie.getFacture().getImputation()));
            sortie.setIdClient(clientService.createClient(sortie.getIdClient()));
            sortie.setFacture(factureService.add(sortie.getFacture()));
            sortie.setIdCommande(commandeService.addCommande(sortie.getIdCommande()));

            // facture.setIdFacture(fa.getFacture().getIdFacture());

            sortie = factureSortieDAO.save(sortie);
            return DtoConverter.convertFacture(sortie);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Transactional
    @Override
    public List<FactureSortieDto> FindAll(int page, int size) {

        int numeroPage = 0;
        int taille = size == 0 ? 10 : size;
        numeroPage = page / taille;
        List<FactureSortie> factures = factureSortieDAO.findAll(new PageRequest(numeroPage, taille)).getContent();

        List<FactureSortieDto> facturesDto = new ArrayList<>();

        for (FactureSortie facture : factures) {
            facturesDto.add(DtoConverter.convertFacture(facture));

        }

        return facturesDto;
    }

    @Override
    public List<FactureSortieDto> find(Date dateStart, Date dateEnd, Integer pieceNumberStart, Integer pieceNumberEnd,
            ClientDto idClient, ProjetDto projet, Double montantTVACStart, Double montantTVACEnd, List<String> UUIDs,
            int first, int max, String sortField, String sortOrder) {
        Mapper mapper = new DozerBeanMapper();
        List<FactureSortie> factures;
        Client client=null;
        if(idClient!=null)
         client= mapper.map(idClient, Client.class);
        Projet project=null;
        if(projet!=null)
            project = mapper.map(projet, Projet.class);


        factures = this.factureSortieDAO.findWithCriterias(dateStart, dateEnd, pieceNumberStart, pieceNumberEnd, client,
                project, montantTVACStart, montantTVACEnd, UUIDs, first, max, sortField, sortOrder);

        List<FactureSortieDto> facturesDto = new ArrayList<>();

        for (FactureSortie facture : factures) {
            facturesDto.add(DtoConverter.convertFacture(facture));

        }

        return facturesDto;
    }

    @Override
    public long count(Date dateStart, Date dateEnd, Integer pieceNumberStart, Integer pieceNumberEnd,
            ClientDto idClient, ProjetDto projet, Double montantTVACStart, Double montantTVACEnd, List<String> UUIDs) {
        Client client=null;
        if(idClient!=null)
         client= mapper.map(idClient, Client.class);
        Projet project=null;
        if(projet!=null)
            project = mapper.map(projet, Projet.class);

        return this.factureSortieDAO.Count(dateStart, dateEnd, pieceNumberStart, pieceNumberEnd, client, project,
                montantTVACStart, montantTVACEnd, UUIDs);
    }

    @Override
    public long countAll() {
        return this.factureSortieDAO.count();
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly=false)
    public void deleteFacture(FactureSortieDto f) {
        FactureSortie facture = DtoConverter.convertFactureDto(f);
        facture=this.factureSortieDAO.findOne(facture.getIdFacture());
        this.factureSortieDAO.delete(facture);
        this.factureService.delete(facture.getFacture());

    }
}
```

> Here is my FactureSortieDAO:

```
package be.afelio.GEDFacture.dao;



import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Sort;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import be.afelio.GEDFacture.entities.FactureSortie;

public interface FactureSortieDAO extends JpaRepository<FactureSortie, Integer>,FactureSortieDAOCustom{
      List<FactureSortie> findAll(Sort sort);





     }
```

Comment: you could print your sql and see if the delete statement is issued. Once you see the query you could try to run directly, may be there are some constraints that dont allow this (`@OneToMany`) etc

Comment: is the method public void deleteFacture(FactureSortieDto f) declared in the interface FactureSortieService.